# How to set AWS EKS nodes to use gp3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm trying to set my EKS nodes to use gp3 as volume. It's using the default gp2 but I would like to change it to gp3. I'm using terraform to build the infrastructure and the `aws_eks_cluster` resource (I'm not using the `module "eks"`). Here is a simple snippet:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name     = var.name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.cluster.arn
  version  = var.k8s_version
}


resource "aws_eks_node_group" "cluster" {
  capacity_type   = var.node_capacity_type
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
  disk_size       = random_id.node_group.keepers.node_disk
  instance_types  = split(",", random_id.node_group.keepers.node_type)
  node_group_name = "${var.name}-${local.availability_zones[count.index]}-${random_id.node_group.hex}"
  node_role_arn   = random_id.node_group.keepers.role_arn
  subnet_ids      = [var.private ? aws_subnet.private[count.index].id : aws_subnet.public[count.index].id]
  version         = var.k8s_version
}
```

I tried to set up the `kubernetes_storage_class` resource but it's only changing for volumes used by the pods (PV/PVC). I would like to change the nodes volume to gp3.

I didn't find in the documentation and in the github how to do that. Was anyone able to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to setup your [own launch template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template) and then reference it in `aws_eks_node_group` - [launch_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#launch_template) argument.

Launch template allows you to configure [disk type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#volume_type). AWS provides [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html) on how to write a launch template correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In case, the person who asked the question or someone else is looking for code snippets, you can see this answer.

Prerequisites:

- AWS IAM role used should have the following 3 AWS Managed Policies:

  - `AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy`
  - `AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy`
  - `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly`
- `vpc_security_group_ids` should have the AWS security groups that you want to attach to your AWS EC2 instance. It must have the default EKS cluster security group.

Your Terraform code will change as follows to create an AWS Launch Template as Terraform resource and use it in the EKS Node Group Terraform resource:

```yaml
resource "aws_launch_template" "aws_launch_template_example" {
  name                   = "staging-node-group"
  image_id               = "ami-0fb932036294318ad" # amazon-eks-node-1.23-v20230607
  instance_type          = "m5.xlarge"
  ebs_optimized          = true
  update_default_version = true

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

    ebs {
      volume_size           = "20"
      volume_type           = "gp3"
      encrypted             = true
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    "xxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxxx"
  ]

  user_data = base64encode(<<-EOF
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="
--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
#!/bin/bash
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh EKS-CLUSTER-NAME
--==MYBOUNDARY==--\
  EOF
  )

  monitoring {
    enabled = false
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      "Name"        = "staging-node-group"
      "Environment" = "staging"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "aws_eks_node_group_example" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_launch_template.aws_launch_template_example
  ]

  cluster_name    = "EKS-CLUSTER-NAME"
  node_group_name = "EKS-NODE-GROUP-NAME"
  node_role_arn   = "xxxxxxxxx"

  subnet_ids      = [
    "xxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxxx"
  ]

  launch_template {
    name    = aws_launch_template.aws_launch_template_example.name
    version = aws_launch_template.aws_launch_template_example.latest_version
  }

  labels = {
    project = "EKS-NODE-GROUP-NAME"
  }

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = "1"
    max_size     = "2"
    min_size     = "1"
  }

  tags = {
    "Name"        = "staging-node-group"
    "Environment" = "staging"
  }
}
```